# How to change an existing server's IP address?

Tags: google-compute-engine

Is it possible to programmatically change an instance's IP address from one ephemeral address to another, ideally without rebooting the instance?

I tried:

```
gcloud compute instances delete-access-config --zone <zone> --access-config-name="External NAT" <instance-name>
gcloud compute instances add-access-config --zone <zone> --access-config-name="External NAT" <instance-name>
```

or switching from a ephemeral address to a static IP and back, but it GCE keeps on reusing the same 1-2 IP addresses. I want to avoid reusing the same IP addresses.

Comment: I have tried to remove the IP of instance and than assigning a ephemeral IP and also have tried changing it to static and back, my IP was changed to another IP after 2 tries the first time. But this behavior is not permanent, because second time it took 4 tries to do same. So based on your use case its not very efficient because you cannot rely on it.

Comment: Moreover as per the documentation the ephemeral IP may change if the instance is rebooted after a failure or once you create a new instance.

Comment: Gili, was the answer below of any use?

Comment: Downvoting, with apologies (see above).

Comment: @halfer responded to your answer below.

Comment: OK, thank you for getting back to your respondent (it wasn't me, but I noticed it was not replied to).

Comment: You can have an answer for that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32634489/how-to-setup-static-ip-to-vm-hosted-on-google-compute-engine-instance/45888838#45888838)

Comment: @EliuX The answer you linked to does not answer my question. I do not wish to use static IP addresses. I want to transition from one ephemeral address to another.

Comment: As ephemeral ips are allocated by google cloud, you shouldnt be able to do that because that other ephemeral ip might not be available. You can only [promote an ephemeral ip to a static one](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#promote_ephemeral_ip) because it was first allocated by google cloud for you and now you want to keep it.

Answer (score 4):

You can accomplish this indirectly using static routes, as described at https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances-and-network#staticnetworkaddress.

Comment: I don't consider this a valid answer because I am trying to exclude ephemeral IPs, not static ones.